# $T \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathbb{F})$ and the vector $u \in V$ does not lie in $\ker(T)$. Is $V = \ker(T)\oplus \mathrm{span}(u)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in \mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathbb{F})$ and the vector $u \in V$ does not lie in $\ker(T)$. Is there a way to prove that $V = \ker(T) \oplus \mathrm{span}(u)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $v \in V$ we have

$$ v = \left(v - \frac{T(v)}{T(u)} \cdot u\right) + \frac{T(v)}{T(u)} \cdot u. $$

The left hand side belongs to $\ker(T)$ and the right hand side belongs to $\mathrm{span}(u)$ which shows that $V = \mathrm{ker}(T) + \mathrm{span}(u)$. Since their intersection is trivial, the sum is direct.